# React Native binary rejected by Apple for using non-public API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, app-store

```
From Apple
Performance - 2.5.1

Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:

: setResult: 

The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.
```

I search the term `setResult` and I think this belongs to the facebook login package that I was using

```
xxxx$ grep -Rnis 'setResult:' *
Binary file ios/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit matches
Binary file node_modules/react-native-facebook-login/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit matches
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend filing an issue on [their Github project](https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login). They shouldn't be using private APIs and I'm sure would want to know that it's resulted in an App Store rejection.

EDIT: OP posted an issue and it appears they aren't the only one with that issue.

https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login/issues/155

Comment: Is this not an issue with `FBSDKCoreKit` itself?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. Apple rejected our app because of a method named `setResult` that is part of the FacebookSDK. It is not a call to a non-public API, but just a method that has coincidentally the same name.

Someone filed a bug at developers.facebook.com. This is Facebook's response:

> Hi all,
>
> I've checked with our Mobile SDK team and also checked this myself
>   personally in our SDK source
>
> The call to setResult in FBSDKCoreKit is not to a private API, it's to
>   this method from the Bolts Framework:
>
> https://boltsframework.github.io/docs/ios/Classes/BFTaskCompletionSource.html#//api/name/setResult:
>
> At this time there aren't any plans to change our usage of this
>   method, and it appears to be being flagged incorrectly by whatever
>   Apple are using to detect private API usage
>
> We recommend you reach out to Apple and have them check your app again
>   and verify that there isn't actually private API usage
>
> I've also asked if our mobile SDK team can contact Apple about this,
>   but I'm unsure if that's something we can do
>
> Regards, Stephen

The bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/294032807641661/

We successfully appealed to the App Review Board, by explaining why it is not a call to a private API.